# How to change font size with a popup Slider in kivy?

Tags: popup, slider, kivy, python-3.5

hi here is my code of a simple RSTDocument editor.
i am trying to change base font size for RSTdocument using a slider in a popup. how can i do this ?? i tried using `slider_id.value` but it didn't work.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_string('''
<RST_GUI>:

    padding: 5
    spacing: 2
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (.5, .1)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        Button:
            text: 'Font Size'
            on_press: root.font_size()
    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: textinput
            tab_width: 5
        Splitter:
            sizeable_from: 'right'
            min_size: '5'
            RstDocument:
                show_errors: True
                base_font_size: #slider_id.value or something possible?
                text: textinput.text

<font_size>:

    size_hint: (.5, .3)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    title: "  Font size: " + str(slider_id.value)
    Slider:
        min: 20
        max: 50
        value:31
        step: 1
        id: slider_id


''')


class RST_GUI(BoxLayout):

    def font_size(self):
        font_size().open()    

class font_size(Popup):
    pass

class RST(App):
    def build(self):
        return RST_GUI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RST().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An id is limited in scope to the rule it is declared in, therefore, you can not do `base_font_size: slider_id.value`. There are several ways to do what you want, one possibility is to create an attribute in your `RST_GUI` class  that is an instance of the popup and use a `NumericProperty` to set the font size:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


Builder.load_string('''
<RST_GUI>:
    font_size: 31
    padding: 5
    spacing: 2
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (.5, .1)
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.5}
        Button:
            text: 'Font Size'
            on_press: root.open_font_popup()

    BoxLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: textinput
            tab_width: 5

        Splitter:
            sizeable_from: 'right'
            min_size: '5'
            RstDocument:
                show_errors: True
                base_font_size: root.font_size
                text: textinput.text

<FontSizePopup>:
    font_size: slider_id.value
    size_hint: (.5, .3)
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': 0.5}
    title: "  Font size: " + str(slider_id.value)
    Slider:
        min: 20
        max: 50
        value:31
        step: 1
        id: slider_id
''')


class RST_GUI(BoxLayout):
    font_size = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RST_GUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.font_popup = FontSizePopup()
        self.font_popup.bind(font_size=self.change_font_size)

    def open_font_popup(self):
        self.font_popup.open()

    def change_font_size(self, instance, value):
        self.font_size = value


class FontSizePopup(Popup):
    pass


class RST(App):
    def build(self):
        return RST_GUI()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    RST().run()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it helped me  alot, if you don't mind would you like to share other methods too, because i like learning, i'll be thankful to you.